# Write hyperlink inside the Zend Form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am using *Zend-Framework* in my project. I made a login form using the Zend Form that contains the User Id and Passwords fields with a submit button. Everything is working fine in the login form.

How do I add **two hyperlinks inside the login form** that is one for the **Sign-Up** and other for the **Forget Password**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've faced the same problem before, and solved it by creating a custom Zend_Form_Element_Html, as follows:

```
class Zend_Form_Element_Html extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml {
    /**
     * Default form view helper to use for rendering
     * @var string
     */
    public $helper = 'formNote';

    public function isValid($value, $context = null) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, in your form you just have to do the following:

```
$tag = new Zend_Form_Element_Html('forgetPassword');
$tag->setValue('<a href="/forgotten-pwd">Forgotten your password?</a>');
$this->addElement($tag);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

In your viewscript file where you print the form, e.g. `login.phtml`

```
echo $this->form;
```

you can specify any other html markup, e.g. links

```
echo "<p><a href='".$this->url ( array ('controller' => 'authentication',
                                        'action' => 'lostPW' ) )."'>
      Lost pw </a></p>";
```

So you actually do not write it in the form itself but in the view script where you echo the form.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$passwordElement->setDescription('<a href="">Forgot password?</a>');
$passwordElement->getDecorator('Description')->setOption('escape', false);
```

Description decorator will add this text beside your field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript)

Or, create a custom Zend_Form_Element to render HTML elements or ViewScript.

Answer (score 1):

For only decorators use directly in the form try:

```
        $this->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Note(array(
            'name' => 'forgotten',
            'value' => __('Forgot your password?'),
            'decorators' => array(
                array('ViewHelper'),
                array('HtmlTag', array(
                    'tag' => 'a',
                    'href' => $this->getView()->url(array(
                        'remind'
                    ))
                )),

            )
        )), 'forgotten');
```