# Write hyperlink inside the Zend Form and use routes?

Tags: zend-framework

I am having a Log-in form and want to add a "Lost Password" Link inside. I found out that you can use the description to do so. But I have now started to change everything to work with routes and would like to use this also for the Forgot Password Link. is there any chance to do this? I can't find a solution, anyone of you who knows how to do it?

```
 $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('login_password', array(
    'label'         => 'Password',
    'description'   => '<a href="account/lost">Forgot Password ?</a>',
            'required'  => true,    
            ));
$password->getDecorator('description')->setOptions(array('escape' => false, 'placement' => 'APPEND'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a Zend_Form, you don't have access to View_Helpers, as a form does not require a view instance. Therefore you either have to fetch a view in your form's init-method or add the description later (I prefer the latter).

When doing it the first way, you have to fetch the Zend_Controller_Front-instance and then its view, finally call a view helper, e.g. Zend_View_Helper_Url from that view.

The latter can be achieved by adding the description later on, e.g. when you passed the form to your view (or in your controller before passing it to the view):

```
<?php
    $description = '<a href="' . $this->url([...]); . '"'>forgot password?</a>
    $this->form->getElement('login_password')->setDescription($description);
    echo $this->form;
?>
```

Comment: Great answer mahok ! I used the Controller solution, so I get the password element and use the setDescription, after that I use the getDecorator('Description')->setOptions to also include 'escape' => false, otherwise the Hyperlink gets written as a text. Excellent. So easy if you know how to do it :) Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem before, and got answer at

[Write hyperlink inside the Zend Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882797/write-hyperlink-inside-the-zend-form)

May help you also...