# anchor tag in setValue() in Zend Form not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using anchor tag in setValue in zend form but its not creating hyperlink but in other zend form its working fine. How it could be possible? Here is my code

```
$readonly_user_balance->setLabel($translate->translate('LABEL_PROFILE_USER_BALANCE'))
                      ->setValue('<a href="....">Test</a>')       

            ->setAttribs(array('id'=> 'readonly_user_balance', 'class'=>''))

            ->setOrder(11)

            ->setDecorators($decorators);
$this->addElements(array($readonly_user_balance));
$this->setDecorators(array(new Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors(array
                       (
                           'ignoreSubForms' => true,
                           'markupElementLabelEnd' => '</div>',
                           'markupElementLabelStart' => '<div class="errors_field">',
                           'markupListEnd' => '</div>',
                           'markupListItemEnd' => '',
                           'markupListItemStart' => '',
                           'markupListStart' => '<div class="form_errors">'
                       )),
                       'FormElements',
                       array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=>'table','class'=>'form_table',
                                              'cellpadding'=>'0', 'cellspacing'=>'0')),
                       'Form'));
```

and $decorators is

```
$decorators = array( 
        array('Label', array('requiredSuffix' => ' *')),
        array('Description', array('class' => 'f_tooltip','tag' => 'span')), 
        array(array('label_td' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' =>     'f_label')),
        array(array('input_td_open' => 'HtmlTag'),array('tag' => 'td','class' => 'f_input','openOnly' => true, 'placement' => 'append')),
        array('ViewHelper'),    
        array(array('input_td_close' => 'HtmlTag'),array('tag' => 'td','class' => 'f_input','closeOnly' => true, 'placement' => 'append')),
        array(array('label_tr' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr', 'class' => ''))
    );
```

In the second line setValue() is not creating hyperlink fot Test

Comment: Can you edit the html code you want to get?

Comment: I want `setValue('<a href="...">Test</a>')` create hyperlink for _Test_

Comment: when i use `Zend_Debug::dump($readonly_user_balance);` it produces `["_value":protected] => string(67) "<a href='http://localhost/...'>Test</a>"` but in view page it is not displaying hyperlink for _Test_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this can be useful for you:

[Write hyperlink inside the Zend Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882797/write-hyperlink-inside-the-zend-form)

The accepted answer uses a little custom class from the abstract class xhtml, and sets a description or value as you did.

Also, you can do something like

```
 ->setValue('<a href="' .$yourUrl . '">Test</a>')
```

Comment: I am not using any class for that.

Comment: you are saying right @Gounemond. Actually there was mistake by **striptags** that was removing my anchor tag.